# Why does the C runtime not call my exit()?

Tags: c, runtime, crt

The C standard states that...

> ...a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the main function as its argument.

From what I see, this is usually implemented by the C runtime support code (crt0.c) by doing exactly this -- calling `exit` with the return value from `main`.

[glibc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/libc-start.c;h=5d9c3675fa38fcd7ee4e034c103bea4b74606366;hb=HEAD#l339):

```
result = main (argc, argv, __environ MAIN_AUXVEC_PARAM);
exit (result);
```

[Ulysses Libc](https://github.com/evanphx/ulysses-libc/blob/master/src/env/__libc_start_main.c#L46):

```
exit(main(argc, argv, envp));
```

However, when I write my own version of `exit`, it does **not** get called:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void exit( int rc )
{
    puts( "ok" );
    fflush( stdout );
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This does not yield the "ok" output I expected. Apparently I am missing something here?

---

Context: I am implementing a C standard library, just the ISO part, i.e. no crt0.c. I hoped that the existing system runtime would call [my own `exit` implementation](https://rootdirectory.ddns.net/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=PDCLib&path=%2Ftrunk%2Ffunctions%2Fstdlib%2Fexit.c), so "my" cleanup (like flushing and closing streams, handling functions registered with `atexit` etc.) would automatically run on return from a `main` linked to my library. Obviously this is not the case, I just do not understand why not.

Comment: Some of the functionality of the "standard library" is usually split between the library itself and the compiler and its support object and library files. The `exit` and `atexit` functions is usually a thing that is handled by the compiler and its support files rather than the standard library.

Comment: This is simply because the run time is already linked against the original `exit` implementation. Most probably it is inlined into the `_start` function.

Comment: How can you write your own version of `exit` and include stdlib.h at the same time? Is this your own version of it, that is stdlib.c or equivalent?

Comment: @Lundin: Note the context given at the end. [The real code](https://rootdirectory.ddns.net/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=PDCLib&path=%2Ftrunk%2Ffunctions%2Fstdlib%2Fexit.c) is my own `exit`, *and* my own `<stdlib.h>`. The code in the question was merely for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Yeah I read that but it isn't obvious if this .c file is your library implementation or some random test file. I wouldn't expect your std lib to contain main(), for example.

Comment: @Lundin: My lib doesn't contain a `main`, but my test drivers (linking my lib) do, and that is when I realized my `exit` (where I do the calling of `atexit`-registered functions, which includes one for flushing / closing open streams) doesn't get called.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to implement the functions in the C standard library while trying to use some parts of the C runtime (namely what calls the main function and exit).

The part of the code that usually does this is the `_start` function. This is typically the entry point for ELF binaries with the Linux loader.

This `_start` function is defined in the C runtime that your compiler is using and the call to exit is already linked (the address patched into the callsite). It is likely that it is simply inlined into the `_start` function.

To get the `_start` function to call your `exit`, what you have to do is to redefine the `_start` itself. Then you have to make sure that the C runtime's `_start` is not used.

I would go with something like this -

```
// Assuming your have included files that declare the puts and fflush functions and the stdout macro. 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]); // This is here just so that there is a declaration before the call
void _start(void) {
    char *argv[] = {"executable"}; // There is a way to get the real arguments, but I think you will have to write some assembly for that. 

    int return_value = main(1, argv);
    exit(return_value);
    // Control should NEVER reach here, because you cannot return from the _start function
}

void exit(int ret) {
    puts("ok"); 
    fflush(stdout); // Assuming your runtime defines these functions and stdout somewhere. 
    // To simulate an exit, we will just spin infinitely - 
    while(1);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    puts("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can compile and link the file as -

```
gcc test.c -o executable -nostdlib
```

The `-nostdlib` tells the linker to not link against the standard runtime which has the implementation of `_start`.

Now you can execute your executable and it will call your "exit" as you expected and will then keep on looping forever. You can kill it by pressing ctrl+c or sending SIGKILL some other way.

### Appendix

Just for completeness' sake, I also tried to write down the implementation for the rest of the functions.

You can firstly add the following declarations and definitions at the top of your code.

```
#define stdout (1)
int puts(char *s);
long unsigned int strlen(const char *s) {
        int len = 0;
        while (s[len])
                len++;
        return len;
}
int fflush(int s) {
}
void exit(int n);
```

`strlen` is defined as expected and `fflush` is a no-op because we are not implementing buffering for our stdio functions.

Now in a separate file puts.s write the following assembly (assuming x64 linux. Change the syscall numbers and arguments if your platform is different).

```
        .text
        .globl puts
puts:
        movq    %rdi, %r12
        callq    strlen
        movq    $1, %rdi
        movq    %r12, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdx
        movq    $1, %rax
        syscall
        retq
```

This is a simplest implementation of `puts` which calls the strlen function followed by the write syscall.

You can now compile and link everything as -

```
gcc test.c put.s -o executable -nostdlib
```

When I run the produced `executable`, I get the following output -

```
hello world
ok
```

and then the process just hangs. I can kill it by pressing ctrl+c.

Comment: Yep this must be it. OP probably has to start with writing their own crt before anything else. Looking at one random crt for ARM that I work with now, they actually wrote the exit function in inline asm as part of the crt.

Comment: @Lundin: That is what I was hoping to avoid -- since the crt isn't part of what ISO C specifies, I was hoping I could "plug in" to the existing framework at the calling of `main`, without "encroaching" on the platform-specifics of crt0.c...

Comment: @DevSolar you cannot just plug it in because it is statically linked with the rest of the ISO C part of the C runtime. After all that code expects to always run with the ISO C functions that came with it.

Comment: @DevSolar I think it is only the `exit` function that's a special snowflake, every other function including `atexit` should be separate from the crt. Though it is worth checking how `memcpy` and `memset` are implemented too - these will be needed by the crt for initialization of `.data` and `.bss`, so they are likely special cases as well.

Comment: @Lundin: Well, to put it differently -- if my own `exit` doesn't get called, how to I plug in the unwinding of my `atexit` function stack into existing CRT's, without having to implement CRT's for every platform I'd like to support? ;-) Apparently the issue is that crt0.c is *statically* linked with the libc (on the Linuxes I am testing on at least), so there's no "complete" replacing the system libc at that point and I have to rely on the people behind the respective CRTs to actually link to my library to get "full support" from the CRT. Bugger.

Comment: It *is* part of what ISO C specifies, not just the functions. BTW @DevSolar I suggest that you check the osdev.org articles on making a proper cross-compiler, you'd really want to configure your own crt0 into it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: ISO C says nothing about `_start`. I have fully functional implementations of most of libc. I was looking for a way to plug in my post-`main` cleanup to the *existing* CRT, *without* reimplementing it. The valuable part of your answer, to that end, is the observation that `exit` is (probably) *statically* linked to crt0.o, so the answer is effectively "cannot be done from userspace". Or perhaps I need to register *my* `exit` with the *system's* `atexit`, so that the *system* `exit` linked to crt0.o calls the *system* `atexit` processing calling *my* `exit`... messy.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The reference to OSDev's Cross Compiler article is funny, because I have *written* that article back in the day. :-D

Comment: @DevSolar IIRC back in days I couldn't get my cross-compiler quite linking executables properly against my newlib port using that, so it might be that you too have missed something ;)

Comment: @DevSolar btw what I mean with ISO C is that ISO C does not specify that there is a C library that exists in *isolation* from the compiler. They're all part of the same implementation. If you're doing a new C library to compile hosted programs then in fact you're providing a new C implementation that is the compiler with your CRT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195910/discussion-between-devsolar-and-antti-haapala).